# Paypal-US: Billing.Agreement.Cancelled Webhook Event Notification not received on my application

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

Paypal Billing.Agreement.Cancelled Webhook Event Notification is not received on my application upon cancelling the billing agreement .

Please find the steps below that i followed to reproduce the above issue

1) Configured Webhook(My Role as Merchant)

```
i) logged into developer.paypal.com
ii) Go to My Apps & Credentials
iii) Selected Sandbox environment
iv) Created Application
    say abc-webhook-app
    and selected the Sandbox Business Account associated with the buyer's accounts.
v) And then as my webhook event i.e BILLING_AGREEMENTS.AGREEMENT.CANCELLED was not
     showing in the UI, i subscribed for the event through API
     and provided the URL and the event_name in the request body
vi) Then i was able see the configured webhook under the above app-name
```

2) Cancel Billing Agreement(My Role as Buyer)

```
 i) I purchased something from the above merchant say foodie.com sandbox
    and payed through paypal sandbox account
ii) Now Billing Agreement is created in my paypal sandbox account
iii) Now i cancelled the billing agreement for the merchant foodie.com
```

Observations:
I can see the email notifications for the above cancelled billing agreement
in the paypal dashboard

Issue:
Wehook event notification for this event is not received on the configured URL upon cancelling the billing agreeement

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you passed something like that

```
{ 
    "url": "{{WebhookURL}}",
    "event_types":  [
        {
            "name": "BILLING_AGREEMENTS.AGREEMENT.CANCELLED"
        }
        ]
}
```

to: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks.
Then you will be able to see the registered Webhook event in your developer dashboard
=> My apps & credentials => [app name]

Some seconds/minutes after cancelling your Billing Agreement as a buyer (from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/myaccount/autopay/) you should be able to see the webhook that was sent to your endpoint in your developer dashboard => sandbox => Webhook events.
If you can't see it there, then Paypal never sent it out.

ps: Make sure that your endpoint (registered at 'url' above) :

- always returns 200 OK
- is publicly accessible
- accepts POST requests
- no authentication is required